# How to Call a URL from a Windows Task

Tags: url, web-applications, scheduled-tasks

i what to schedule on my server machine a process that runs on a webapplication, by calling a url.

i'm using windows server 2008 / windows 7 ultimate,

is there some special way to do this with powershell or vscript?

what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: is there some special way to do this with powershell or vscript?

A: Yes.  Or C/C+, C#, VB.Net.

If you were on Linux, I'd recommend "wget" (which is also available for Windows):

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/